# How to update a datatable in a dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datatable, dataset

1. I have a Dataset.
2. I fill a datatable in it from an SQL server using a `tableadapter`
3. I extract the data from the dataset using the Rows property. The data goes into an unbound listview
4. I change the data in the list view
5. Now I have to update the List, What would be the right way/approach to do it

What's the proper way to update the datatable from the updated listview
Once the data is back in the datatable what's the proper way to update the sql server?

Answer (score 0):

you can bind your listview on your datatable, so it will be easy to update it (and sql server too)
see this url:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t687274-bind-listview-to-datatable-why-is-this-a-problem.html